# Requesting simplest OpenMP target GPU example

Tags: c++, g++, gpu, openmp

Could someone please give me a simple C++ program using OpenMP with an Nvidia GPU as the target, and give me the line to compile it?

I'm running Ubuntu 19.10 on a dual 8-core Intel Xeon.

Relevant packages I've installed include:

```
g++-9                       9.2.1-9ubuntu2
gcc-9-offload-nvptx         9.2.1-9ubuntu2
libgomp-plugin-nvptx1:amd64 9.2.1-9ubuntu2 
nvptx-tools                 0.20180301-1
```

I've spent hours searching and trying advice, some of it contradictory, and much of it seemingly obsolete.   E.g., I do not want to have to compile the compiler.    Here's my minimal nonworking example:

```
int main() {
  double s;
#pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for reduction(+:s) map(tofrom:s)
  for (int idx = 0; idx < 1000; ++idx) s+= idx;
  std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

How I compiled it:
`g++ target2.cc -fopenmp -fno-stack-protector`

The output:

```
cc1plus: warning: could not emit HSAIL for the function [-Whsa]
cc1plus: note: support for HSA does not implement non-gridified OpenMP parallel constructs.
munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer
mkoffload: fatal error: x86_64-linux-gnu-accel-nvptx-none-gcc-9 terminated with signal 6 [Aborted], core dumped
compilation terminated.
lto-wrapper: fatal error: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9//accel/nvptx-none/mkoffload returned 1 exit status
compilation terminated.
/usr/bin/ld: error: lto-wrapper failed
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[1]    29044 exit 1     g++ target2.cc -fopenmp -fno-stack-protector
```

Help?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how your gcc-offload package was compiled. But you could try using (by adding) the compiler flag '-foffload=nvptx-none'.